# Context-sensitive and turing-complete formal languages

Tags: formal-languages, context-sensitive-grammar

Do you know about any, which can specify context-sensitive grammar? For example * symbol pointer/multiplication ambiguity resolving. I am looking for formal language which will make it possible to resolve such ambiguities. The language, which I am looking for should be well specified.

Edit: I am looking for something like BNF, but should be context-sensitive, actually it should be able to solve [Dangling else](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_else) problem.

Comment: C++ certainly fits the bill (it is highly context-sensitive)

Comment: Ironically, your question is itself ambiguous, or at least I completely fail at parsing it. Could you elaborate/rephrase what kind of thing you're after and what properties it should have?

Comment: I am looking for formal language, which can resolve differences in parsing between pointers and multiplications symbol, without supplying some external routines. Something like BNF, but should be context-sensitive.

Comment: I'm not sure whether context sensitive grammars are enough to tell pointer declarations from multiplications (people always say that's context sensitive, but I've built up the impression that most of them use an informal, possibly very wrong, definition of context sensitivity). In any case, the trivial solution would be any turing complete language; I assume you intended to rule that out by "without supplying some external routines"? If so, you'll have to make that more formal/specific, that wording can mean almost anything.

Answer (score 4):

BNF can resolve ambiguities of this sort by introducing additional rules. For example, in the [Java language spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.9) you find:

```
IfThenStatement:
  if ( Expression ) Statement
IfThenElseStatement:
  if ( Expression ) StatementNoShortIf else Statement
StatementNoShortIf:
  IfThenElseStatementNoShortIf
  ...
IfThenElseStatementNoShortIf:
  if ( Expression ) StatementNoShortIf else StatementNoShortIf
```

...where `StatementNoShortIf` is a `Statement` that can't end with an 'if' that has no 'else'. Thus, if I am parsing `if(a) if(b) c(); else d();`, then the only option is to have `if(b) c(); else d();` bind to `StatementNoShortIf`.